# EditText setError is not showing in FragmentActivities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a form in an Activity, that have their fields validated on an second class (BLL class) and I use setError() method to display the validation message. It works well until then.

But now I need to put this form on an fragment activity. I did all the changes needed and the validation works fine, but the "baloon" is not been showed.

I had searched everywhere, but i couldnt find anything that helps.

Here's my code:

```
public class OrderCustomFieldsFragment extends Fragment {

  public void save() {

    try {
        CustomFieldsBll customFields = new CustomFieldsBll(this.getActivity());
        customFields.validateCustomFields(irrelevant...); 
        ...irrelevant code...
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (CustomException z) {
        if (setError(z.getThrowerField(), z.getMessage()))
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), z.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

  }



  private boolean setError(Integer throwerField, String msg) {
    //If thorwerField is null then is a general error, otherwise is a form field
    if (throwerField == null) {
      //here display an dialog          
      showOKMessage(this.getActivity(), "Pedidos", msg, false);
      return false;
    }
    else {
      try {
          //linearLayout is my view, instanciated in onCreateView method
        TextView customField = (TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(throwerField);
        if (customField != null) {
           customField.setError(msg);
           customField.requestFocus();
           return true;
        }
        else {
          showOKMessage(this.getActivity(), "Pedidos", msg, false);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        showOKMessage(this.getActivity(), "Pedidos", msg, false);
      }
   }

   return false;
  }

}
```

The exception is throwed, the field is found, the error is setted, but only the Toast appears, the error ballon doesnt.
Any ideias?
Thanks